# What all filesystem errors Linux Kernel can detect?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, filesystems, kernel, ext4

There is an option in /etc/fstab to decide what to do with the disk when an error occurs.
errors={continue|remount-ro|panic}

What the possible disk errors that Kernel can catch? Are there any other type of disks errors that can go unnoticed by Kernel?

Answer (score 1):

The errors detected in this context (fstab's mount option `errors=`) are basically write errors caused by bad disk or badly damaged filesystem.

Please note that hard-disk controllers generally mask write errors due to a bad block using an on-the-fly remap of the bad sector/block with a sane one. However, if the disk has no other spare sectors it will raise an uncorrectable error which will trigger the filesystem `errors=` action.

In the same manner, badly damaged filesystem can trigger the `errors=` action due to impossibility of read/write some metadata blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a mount option that determines how a filesystem behaves upon a critical error. You would form a line in the fstab file like so (only an example):

`/dev/sda5 /srv/foo btrfs relatime,errors=continue 0 1`

"Continue", "remount-ro", and "panic" are the three options you have in this field.

To your second question, a rewording is appropriate in that one should ask, "What errors can this particular filesystem catch?" This answer depends entirely on what filesystem you are using, what version that filesystem is, and how you are checking it.

All of that being said, most filesystems can correct some pretty heinous errors when their checker is invoked using `fsck`. Nearly all filesystems must be offline in order to be corrected - with dire consequences if they are online during correction. BTRFS can perform online filesystem scrubs (limited integrity checks), but also has an offline repair functionality for serious filesystem errors.

Errors can go unnoticed in filesystems of all types in various scenarios. One very common one involved a disk changing its data outside of the filesystem interface - either because a disk is going bad or because it was directly manipulated at the block level. This is one limited example, though. There are all kinds of creative and horrible ways to corrupt data, but most of them will be reported by the filesystem module in use (assuming the filesystem is online).